# Get data from second DB based on results of first query

Tags: sql-server, subquery

Need help pulling data from a 2nd database based on the results given in a working query. The shorted value needs to be looked up in the 2nd database to get the full readable name. Hope this makes sense. Any help is appreciated.

**Working query:**

```
USE PData;
SELECT DISTINCT
       Customkey,
       COUNT(*) AS TotalQueries,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status <= '200' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status >= '201' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Failed,
       (CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN status >= '201' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS decimal) / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS FailedPercentage
FROM RQueue AS RQ WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE AddDate >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -60, GETDATE())
GROUP BY CustomKey
ORDER BY 4 DESC,
         5 DESC;
```

**Current results:**

```
CustomKey    TotalQueries    Completed    Failed    FailedPercentage
CA_N         18              0            18        100.00000000000
CA_S         11              0            11        100.00000000000
```

**Desired results:**

```
CustomKey    FullKeyName         TotalQueries    Completed    Failed    FailedPercentage
CA_N         California North    18              0            18        100.00000000000
CA_S         California South    11              0            11        100.00000000000
```

The desired results would add the second column to final results. This would come from:

```
From CustomData.DB
When  CustomKey table matches
return FullKeyName table content
```

Comment: What is your reasoning for using `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` here? Normally a `GROUP BY` will return a distinct set of data, so there is no need for use of `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT`. Do you have a reason for using `WITH (NOLOCK)` here as well, as that can have some severe consequences on the data returned. As for your question, where are the values of `FullKeyName` coming from? Are you simply asking how to perform a `JOIN`? If so, have you had a look at the syntax? What was your attempt to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

Forget you ever learned about nolock - don't use it until you understand what it does and what can happen. Is it safe to use here? Maybe - but Who knows. Often it is included because someone said something about "faster". If you do include it, you should know what it might do and what errors (yep) it might generate and be prepared to respond when errors occur or someone challenges your results.

Next, DISTINCT does nothing useful here. Why do you include it? And lastly, we don't order by ordinal numbers - that a bad habit you should not encourage.

As for your question, just put your current query in a cte and then join that cte as needed. Roughly:

```
with cte as (select ... from dbo.RQueue ...)  --no order by clause here
select <columns you need> 
from cte inner (left?) join <database>.<schema>.<table> as NameLookup
  on cte.CustomKey = NameLookup.CustomKey 
order by cte.Failed desc, cte.FailedPercent desc;
```

Again - this is "roughly" what you want as it involves some guessing. Notice that I added some better practices.

Comment: Thanks SMor and Larnu. I'll chew on that for a while. Afraid I do not have answers to any of your questions although I've been told by the ones above me to always use no lock as i'm tooling around. All of it is new to me anyway. Appreciate the advice.